# Removing Multiple Unique Values from Column in Python

Tags: python, pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwhXl.png)

I am trying to remove the last three digits from the date column. There are 1,417 rows in the data frame that have this problem and are all different numbers. I am using Python and Pandas. I have also attached the dataset that I am working on if there is also something I could do in Excel and then re-upload it. [enter link description here](https://data.world/gmoney/nba-team-records-by-year)

Answer (score 2):

You can use string slicing to remove the last 3 digits as follows.

```
df['date'] = df['date'].str[:-3]
```

Example code:

```
import pandas as pd

date = [
    '2020-01',
    '2020-02',
    '2020-03'
]
df = pd.DataFrame(date, columns=['date'])
df['date'] = df['date'].str[:-3]

print (df)
```

Output:

```
   date
0  2020
1  2020
2  2020
```